# Django one database per user or one in general?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently writing a chat-application for my Website and storing all the Messages in one database, by referring to sender and receiver with a Foreign-key.
Is this really the smartest Idea? I think the site could become slow when everybody is trying to access the same database or when the number of sent messages gets big. Would it be **smarter/faster**, to use **one database per user**, storing his/her messages there? If yes, am i right that this is not really possible to achieve this with Django?

Thanks for your Answer!

Comment: there are some articles out there on how to design a db for chats. No judgement but one database per user seems insane, there are better options!

Comment: @hansTheFranz Thanks for the Answer, i'll google it. I asked this Question so my Ideas would be judged. :D

Comment: One db per user for chats is a bad idea. A regular SQL database (like Postgres or MySQL) can easily handle over thousands of reads/writes per second. For more performance, you can upgrade RAM and CPU. Then there are other database tweaking techniques like sharding and caching etc. I wouldn't worry about performance so early. Focus on shipping the product first. You'll have plenty of time worrying about scaling if and when you get that many users.

Comment: @xyres Okay. Do you think that, for later, this model is good? https://github.com/yoosuf/Messenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be smarter/faster, to use one database per user

Probably not, because you will still have the same quantity of data and just have the overhead of have multiple database instances

> this is not really possible to achieve this with Django?

Django is not a database manager, so the question does not really make sense. For example, Oracle or SQLite allow a single query to access multiple databases. So if you used Oracle with Django, you could have a different database per user. Anyway, even if by default Django only uses one single database connection, it can be configured to use [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/) (thanks to @brunodesthuilliers for the info).

Database design is a rather complex operation: you have to design the tables to structure the data, the indexes, to speed up some accesses and/or enforce uniqueness, and optionaly views to easy request writing. Once this is done (and the database is used), you will have to define recurrent tasks to cleanup the database (index maintenance, archivage and purge of archived data).

If you intend to use a large farm of servers to be able to handle thousands of simultaneous accesses, a SQL database can indeed become a bottleneck, and you should considere NoSQL databases to dispatch the load on independant servers. But in this use case, Django would just be a casting error. Anyway, I know no example of real world use case where multiple databases are used just for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not that optimistic to calculate with thousands of simultaneous accesses. So it's good to know that different databases wont improve performance. I Think i will stick to django and sgl. I've found this Database-Structure. Do you think it is a good? https://github.com/yoosuf/Messenger.

Comment: " Of course as Django only uses one single database connection" => you may want to [double-check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/) ;-) (everything else is spot on though)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Merci. I knew that Django was smart, but was not aware it was that smart. I have edited my post...

Comment: @SergeBallesta pas de quoi ;-)